# Xamarin - Deployment failed using an AVD

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm using `MSVS2015Pro` with `C#`/`Xamarin`.

I successfully built the application.

But when trying to deploy the application to an AVD (Android Virtual Device) I get the following error:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
```

Below you have the detailed log:

```
2>Starting emulator Android_Accelerated_x86 ...
2>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd Android_Accelerated_x86 -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86
2>emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
2>Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
2>CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine
2>Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86 cannot be started.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

But the point is that I have already installed the:

> Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)

through the `Android SDK Manager` as you can see on the following image:

[image]

Any idea on how to make a successful deployment on this AVD?

I tried running: `Android_Accelerated_x86 (Android 6.0 - API 23)`

[image]

Comment: Check if you have the hyper-v service running. You also have to check if your computer supports hardware acceleration, go check it on google. You should also try to use genymotion as an emulator, there is a free version accessible wich works kinda well

Comment: I think my laptop doesn't support hardware acceleration. Then I have a question: given my circumstances, can I develop for mobiles without having to spend too much time when deploying?. I could deploy to my real phone, but I don't know if that's slower than deploying to an AVD. What Can I do? I don't wanna do things in a very slow manner.

Comment: It depends on your phone quality. In most cases (from my experience) phone linked to computer > to emulator.
But you should definitely give a try to Genymotion, i think it's one of the most performant android emulator manager i've met so far. Way better than the ones included with Visual Studio or Eclipse. But be ready to meet a lot of trouble with emulators configurations, whatever is solution you choose

Comment: @yan-yankelevich thanks you very much!